Meaning of cut vertex in Whitehead graph in the sense of language
I recently reading Whitehead algorithm in paper of Stallings (without bothering 3-manifolds). Whitehead graph and the cut vertex play an important role. Let us consider one example from Stallings where $\alpha = abad^{-1}cac^{-1}aab^{-1}d^{-1}\in F_4$ and $F_4=\langle a,b,c,d\rangle$. We denote the language $L(\alpha)$ by the set of reduced cyclic subwords of $\alpha$, and $\Gamma$ its Whitehead graph. One can check that $a,a^{-1}$ are two cut vertex of $\Gamma$ and there exists a Whitehead automorphism $\varphi_{(Y,Z;a)}$ taking $a$ to $a$, $b$ to $ba^{-1}$, $c$ to $aca^{-1}$ and $d$ to $ad$ such that it reduces the complexity of $\alpha$. Here, $Y=\{a,b^{-1},d\}$ and $Z =\{a^{-1},b,c,c^{-1},d^{-1}\}$.
In my mind, Whitehead graph gives a way to trace the language of subwords $L(\alpha)$. However, I don't have an exact interpretation of cut vertex in terms of language. For example, $a$ is a cut vertex in the above example and what does it imply for a property in $L(\alpha)$ and vice versa? So my questions are:

Do we have an interpretation on cut vertex of Whitehead graph in terms of language? (I'm also planning to read the 3-manifold picture now to see if there's anything.)

In above example, how many Whitehead automorphisms with special letter $a^{\pm 1}$ (and will reduce cyclic word length of $\alpha$) can we have? Does it relate to the number of times $a^{\pm 1}$ appearing in $\alpha$?


The second question is from the proof of Lemma 3.2 of Bestvina, Feighn 2014 and leads me into question 1.
Thanks for your help in advance!
Edit: Make my question a bit less vague according and thanks to the comments!

You say you "don't have a picture for the cut vertex". But then you ask for an interpretation "in terms of language" which does not seem like a request for a "picture". So I'm unsure what you are asking for.

@LeeMosher I am sorry about the vagueness. By picture, I mean an interpretation in terms of language. For example, if $a$ is a cut vertex what does it mean for a property of $L(\alpha)$ and vice versa.

Well, in terms of language I would just point to the proof of the Whitehead algorithm and the step where the cut vertex is used. The outcome of that step is that one changes free basis (by a Whitehead transformation) and shortens the cyclic word length of $\alpha$. Is this the kind of thing you want to know?

@LeeMosher Thanks for your response! Originally, my thought was that cut vertex gives information that if any $w\in L(\alpha)$ has a letter $x\in Y$ and a letter in $y\in Z$ we must have $a^{\pm 1}$ in the middle. I am wondering if there are more I can say about elements in $L(\alpha)$. Maybe that's all I can say, but this information is quite useful already. That is, $\alpha$ contains a segment $xa^ky$ for $k\geq 1$ where the Whitehead transformation will reduce the cyclic word length!

(Not related to this question)Maybe another idea I should keep in mind is the cut vertex comes from the Whitehead graph of the almost rose assuming
is separable/simple. The second question follows from your comment that the Whitehead transformation will at least cancel one $a^{\pm 1}$, so there are at most $k$ such transformations where $k$ is the occurrence of $a$ in $\alpha$. Thanks again for your help!
